# Jquery Hide And Show not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, toggle

this is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#lnkButtonSchools').click(function () {
        var dvSchools = $('#divSchools');
        dvSchools.toggle();
    });
});
```

this is the declaration of div whics i want to toggle

```
 <div id="divSchools" runat="server" style="display:none">
```

this is the anchor button

```
 <a id="lnkButtonSchools" runat="server" class="span8 pad2" style="margin-left:0px;font-size:12px;">Limit by School</a>
```

The div is not at all coming when clicking anchorbutton. what is the mistake?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/7adkG/ Are you sure you are loading jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to prevent default action of the anchor using [`.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) like:

```
$('#<%= lnkButtonSchools.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dvSchools = $('#<%= divSchools.ClientID %>');
    dvSchools.toggle();
});
```

Also, use `<%= lnkButtonSchools.ClientID %>` for getting the proper ID of the anchor, since your client ID mode is not static,

Comment: With Client ID itself it is working fine. even e.preventdefault() is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $('#<%=lnkButtonSchools.ClientID %>').click(function () {
     $('#<%=divSchools.ClientID %>').toggle();
     return false; 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be because the anchor tag gets a trigger and loads the page.

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $('#lnkButtonSchools').click(function () {
     var dvSchools = $('#divSchools');
     dvSchools.toggle();
     return false; // this code
  });
});
```

This will force the code to return to the current page and stop further execution. So stopping the anchor tag to load a new page. I hope this way the div will get a `display: block` since your code is perfect; assuming you have connected your web page to the .js file correctly.